# Error while adding UDF in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have to add a UDF in hive.
The query I am trying is :

```
create function strip1 as 'com.hadoopbook.hive.Strip' using jar '/home/hduser/Hadoop-tutorial/hadoop-book-master/ch17-hive/src/main/java/com/hadoopbook/hive/Strip.jar'
```

But I am getting a exception as :

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask. Hive warehouse is non-local, but /home/hduser/Hadoop-tutorial/hadoop-book-master/ch17-hive/src/main/java/com/hadoopbook/hive/Strip.jar specifies file on local filesystem. Resources on non-local warehouse should specify a non-local scheme/path

Can  anyone tell how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Three options:

1. copy the jar on hdfs and use that path.

OR

2. as error is telling you: In the `$HIVE_HOME/conf` directory there is the `hive-default.xml` and/or `hive-site.xml` which has the `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` property. add `hdfs:/` to this path, and restart/re-run the hive shell/script:

   ```
    <property>
      <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
      <value>hdfs://usr/hive/warehouse </value>
      <description>location of the warehouse directory</description>
    </property>
   ```

OR

3. if you are running hive queries from hive shell then:

   ```
    hive> set hive.metastore.warehouse.dir;
    hive.metastore.warehouse.dir=/user/hive/warehouse
   ```

   above command prints the path, just prefix the `hdfs:/` to it as below and then re-run your hive command(s) :

   ```
   hive> set hive.metastore.warehouse.dir="hdfs://user/hive/warehouse";
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could setting the configuration `hive.aux.jars.path` to `/home/hduser/Hadoop-tutorial/hadoop-book-master/ch17-hive/src/main/java/com/hadoopbook/hive/` 
and create hive udf function via below command:

```
create function strip1 as 'com.hadoopbook.hive.Strip'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first try to add UDF jar to a hdfs location instead of the local directory:

```
  $ add jar "hdfs://user/cloudera/hive/udf/Strip.jar"
```

and then create hive function as below:

```
  $ create function test_function as "com.hadoopbook.hive.Strip"
```

Hope this helps :)